# Issue removing a link within the global navigation bar

Tags: 2013, global-navigation, menu

I'm a site administrator trying to delete a couple of unneeded links from the global navigation bar within a top site.

There's a site with a drop-down menu and the link is in there. When I go to navigation and edit links (SP2013), I'll find the link in the drop down menu and there's an X next to it.

When I try to click on this X to disable the link, nothing happens. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Are you adding them to global navigation directly or they were added automatically when you have created that sites?

Comment: Which browser are you trying this in? I've seen issues with similar things using Internet Explorer recently, where Firefox, Edge or Chrome all appear to work correctly.

Comment: They were there already when my business migrated to from SharePoint2010 to 2013.